# 123-reg: Enabling PHP in their Starter package

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting, mod-userdir

One of my clients has been with 123-reg for years and wanted to continue to use their hosting.  Upon starting a new '[Starter Package](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/web-hosting/comparisonpage.shtml)' I have been unable to do the simplest thing and enable PHP.

The current situation is that any .php file simply isn't parsed and is just rendered to the browser as text.  For instance:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Instead of doing something useful, is rendered as text.

Their support is being next to useless. Thus far I have had two responses from them, the first saying:

> With the hosting service attached for the domain devotionafrica.org PHP is a enabled by default. If you wish to upload a PHP based website within the hosting space it will run as expected and display online.

And then later

> Try to upgrade the hosting service to the Business package to see if the upgrade will enable the scripting language.

I've read about the [userdir module being enabled](http://binfalse.de/2011/02/apache-not-parsing-php-files/) causing similar problems. Do you think that this could be the reason here too?

Have you any suggestions on what I can do to get 123-reg to fix their problem?

I am fully aware that 123-reg does not have the best reputation in the world but unfortunately my hands are tied on the choice.  Please no suggestions to move provider.

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing we can do to help you. This is clearly a problem for your hosting provider to resolve and from personal experience of that company I know how painful that is going to be. If your time has any real price it will be considerably cheaper for your customer to just transfer out to a new hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the starter package should support php, then point the  support tech to the failing script, in response to the "try upgrading to business", simply reply you'd be happy to if they were to provide the business package at no extra cost.

Failing that you can cite the service not "being fit for purpose" and demand a full refund, per your statutory rights as a consumer.

There's no short road on this, from the information you have provided you are having to fight against a support team who  couldn't care about their entry level packages, is this really worth the hours of debating you will have to go through for such a small return?

Why not consider a cloud provider, and get a complete instance you can manage yourself?

On that note you would be better off convincing the client to go else where, rather than headdesking yourself to the other side of the planet.